# In Django cursor.execute("select ..") randomly returns None

Tags: python, mysql, django, openshift

I am running Django + MySql on OpenShift server and have this problem.

Code:

```
from django.db import connection

...

cursor = connection.cursor()
somedate = calculateSomeDate()
query = "SELECT id FROM levelbuffer WHERE START > '%s' ORDER BY START ASC LIMIT 1" % somedate 

print "First select: " + query
cursor.execute(query)

sql_result = cursor.fetchone()

if not sql_result == None:
    gameId = int(sql_result[0])
    cursor.fetchall()    #To clear anything left behind (this wasn't here before, but no changes appeared after adding)
    query = "SELECT gamescores.skore, users.name FROM gamescores JOIN users ON gamescores.userId = users.id where gamescores.gameId = " + str(gameId) + " ORDER BY skore ASC"
    cursor.execute(query);

    #cursor.execute("SELECT gamescores.skore, users.name FROM gamescores JOIN users ON gamescores.userId = users.id where gamescores.gameId = %s ORDER BY skore ASC", (gameId))
    print "Second select " + query
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

The weird thing is, that the row is sometimes None and sometimes it contains wanted values. I cant figure out, what i am missing. The first query works fine every time.

When I try to perform the second query printed in log on phpmyadmin - works always fine.

Comment: Do you have this same issue when testing it locally on your computer, or running it on another service? Or is it only on OpenShift that you have the issue?

Comment: I havent tried another server yet. I will try run local server as soon as possible. Just hypoteticaly, if it would run properly what could be the cause? I edited the code a little bit, just to show, how i get the cursor etc. I mean - am i using cursor right? Whats the difference betwen first query and the second one? Both querys are OK as SQL and should return value.

Comment: If you copy and paste the first and second query right after each other you will see a difference in how you are using them.  Technically I think in the second query you are using an unquoted string for the gameId also?

Comment: Maybe try the second query here (https://gist.github.com/developercorey/5cd5ad35482c32ec4f19), i think %i is correct, but am not 100% sure

Comment: I dont think this is the problem, because when i put the unqoated (i tried the quated too with same result) directly in phpmyadmin it works. And if it would be wrong, it wouldnt work at all not just sometimes, i think.  As you can see the commented code, at first i tried the "proper" way - pass it as the argument to execute, but the problem was there, so i used this to be able to print the query into log. Couldnt there be something that i should do between two querys that im missing?